# How to apply a private label with mklabel celearcase command?

Tags: clearcase, vob

I'm tring to apply a personal label on a file in clearcase vob.
I've used the command:

```
cleartool mklabel MY_LABEL TestFile.txt@@\main\1
```

End the result is:

> cleartool: Error: label type "MY_LABEL" not found in VOB "\TEST_vob"
>   and no global type defin cleartool: Error: Unable to create label
>   "MY_LABEL" on "TestFile.txt" version "\main\1".

I execute the command from command line in the same level of the file. 
Am I using the command incorrectly, or is the command locked by a CC admin?

Comment: Did the answer below work?

Comment: @VonC, It works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should create the label *type* first using the [`cleartool mklbtype`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklbtype.htm) command

```
M:\myView\TEST_vob\aFolder> cleartool mklbtype -nc MY_LABEL
Created label type 'MY_LABEL'.
```

Then try your `mklabel` command again.